# Using font data (.ttf or .otf) vs image data (png or jpg) in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode

I often use font data (.ttf or .otf) in Swift to change font of UILabel. But sometimes I use only show numbers in UILabel and think which is better using font data or image data of each numbers like "1_image.png", "2_image.png", "3_image.png"...

Of course if I want to show many characters like articles and messages I should import font file in project. But I'm not sure which is better to show only numbers in the specific situation like showing user game ranking and scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is almost always better to use a font -- as long as you are allowed to distribute it. Some of the advantages of fonts are:

- They scale
- No need to bother about pixel resolutions
- More options to align them (like baseline etc.)
- Better support for accessibility (like adjusting the contrast etc.)